# HTML5 Ampersand and QueryString

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493405/do-i-really-need-to-encode-as-amp) and I understand that the HTML5 specifications say that. Period.

But I'm creating a MVC3 app that uses Google Charts API (images) and I need to use  images with links to a google adress and they have a querystring. Just like this:

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=440x220&cht=t&chco=EFEFEF&chld=BRJPUS&chd=t:20,30,50&chtm=world
```

I've tested getting a working chart and change a single ampersand to & and the chart returned a error from Google.

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you post a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo, showing what does, and doesn't, work? I'm not sure I understand your question as it stands (but it *is* late in the UK, or early, so that might be why...).

Comment: Not sure I understand your question either.  Putting regular old ampersands (&) in the querystring of your anchor hrefs should never generate an error.  No error for any other element attribute either.  What's the real issue?  Does `<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=440x220&cht=t&chco=EFEFEF&chld=BRJPUS&chd=t:20,30,50&chtm=world
">` not work?

Comment: If the *markup* in the browser is `<a href="http://foo/a&amp;b">link</a>` the *link* read by the browser is "http://foo/a&b". Thus `&` should *always* (with a few exclusions such as `<script>`) be encoded as `&amp;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing to fix in your generated url. It works just fine and generates an image.

Are you actually referring to & amp; (without the space of course)
If thats the case and it causes an error, UrlDecode the querystring as its encoded.
UrlDecode:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx

Comment: Found what was wrong. I've tested the url directly on the browser and got an error. When I changed the & to & amp; on the code, the browser rendered it correctly.