# What is &amp used for

Tags: forms, html

Is there any difference in behaviour of below URL.

I don't know why the `&amp;` is inserted, does it make any difference ?

```
www.testurl.com/test?param1=test&amp;current=true
```

versus

```
www.testurl.com/test?param1=test&current=true
```

Comment: Related: [Do I really need to encode as amp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493405/do-i-really-need-to-encode-as-amp)

Comment: Can you give a context? Is this in a form action? Just displayed on a page?

Comment: @user470184 I didn't downvote but considered it.  There's a ton of information already on SO concerning this issue.

Comment: "Generic behavior" is still pretty vague. Are you wondering about something like `<p>www.testurl.com/test?param1=test&amp;current=true</p>` or `<a href="www.testurl.com/test?param1=test&amp;current=true">linky</a>`?

Comment: @ jprofitt <a href="www.testurl.com/test?param1=test&amp;current=true">linky</a>

Answer (score 193, accepted):

`&` is HTML for "Start of a character reference".

`&amp;` is the character reference for "An ampersand".

`&current;` is not a standard character reference and so is an error (browsers may try to perform error recovery but you should not depend on this).

If you used a character reference for a real character (e.g. `&trade;`) then it (™) would appear in the URL instead of the string you wanted.

(Note that depending on the version of HTML you use, you may have to end a character reference with a `;`, which is why `&trade=` will be treated as ™. HTML 4 allows it to be ommited if the next character is a non-word character (such as `=`) but some browsers (Hello Internet Explorer) have issues with this).

Answer (score 16):

HTML doesn't recognize the `&` but it will recognize `&amp;` because it is equal to "&" in HTML

I looked over this post someone had made: http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum21/8851.htm

Answer (score 9):

My Source: http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html#amp

> Another common error occurs when including a URL which contains an
> ampersand ("&"):

This is invalid:

> a href="foo.cgi?chapter=1&section=2&copy=3&lang=en"

Explanation:

> This example generates an error for "unknown entity section" because
> the `"&"` is assumed to begin an entity reference. Browsers often
> recover safely from this kind of error, but real problems do occur in
> some cases. In this example, many browsers correctly convert &copy=3
> to ©=3, which may cause the link to fail. Since ⟨ is the HTML
> entity for the left-pointing angle bracket, some browsers also convert
> &lang=en to 〈=en. And one old browser even finds the entity §,
> converting &section=2 to §ion=2.

So the goal here is to avoid problems when you are trying to validate your website. So you should be replacing your ampersands with `&amp;` when writing a URL in your markup.

> Note that replacing `&` with `&amp`; is only done when writing the URL in
> HTML, where `"&"` is a special character (along with "<" and ">"). When
> writing the same URL in a plain text email message or in the location
> bar of your browser, you would use `"&"` and not `"&amp;"`. With HTML, the
> browser translates `"&amp;"` to `"&"` so the Web server would only see `"&"`
> and not `"&amp;"` in the query string of the request.

Answer (score 2):

That's a great example. When `&current` is parsed **into a text node** it is converted to `¤t`. When parsed **into an attribute value**, it is parsed as `&current`.

If you want `&current` in a text node, you should write `&amp;current` in your markup.

The gory details are in the [HTML5 parsing spec - Named Character Reference State](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#named-character-reference-state)

Answer (score -3):

if you're doing a string of characters. 
make:

```
let linkGoogle = 'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1'; 
let origin = '&origin=' + locations[0][1] + ',' + locations[0][2];


aNav.href = linkGoogle + origin;
```

Comment: The question is about `&amp` in HTML, not `&` in URLs.