# Display specific sheet with edit mode in iframe

Tags: html, google-sheets, iframe

My iframe code:

```
<iframe height="750" style="width:100%" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<?=$google_sheet_id;?>/edit?rm=minimal#gid=<?=$_SESSION['customers_gid'];?>"></iframe>
```

that displays Google Sheets with all sheets like:

[image: Several tabs]

i want to display only `Customers` sheet.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty late, but simple answer to future buddies.

Open google docs > click on "File" > Share > Publish to web > it will ask you to Share "All docs" or Sheet1 or Sheet2 > select which one you want.

**Then you will get code something like**

```
<iframe      src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQrvFsPs7Fpkaao0XvwIUc54WwPsQ4zzlyaEYV6-4JsSEfgZA4YLJpTwlA1pgurUvVCxRzBQ_8OqFJa/pubhtml?                   gid=23663673&amp;single=true&amp"
```

Extra code and its explanation, add it before < / iframe >. Also "amp" at end will be constant but true, false can be changed according to your needs.

1. For setting size -

   height="410" width="100%"
2. For hiding Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3 options while showing on site -

   widget=false&amp
3. For hiding header option of sheet -

   headers=false&amp
4. For hiding title bar showing the spreadsheet name above the sheet -

   chrome=false&amp
5. For selecting data of specific range (A1 and B19 is range, so change them accordingly, but don't change "%3A" in it, as it works as : this symbol here, if you use : it will show error -

   range=A1%3AB19

**Full code will look like**

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQrvFsPs7Fpkaao0XvwIUc54WwPsQ4zzlyaEYV6-4JsSEfgZA4YLJpTwlA1pgurUvVCxRzBQ_8OqFJa/pubhtml?           gid=1273789&amp;widget=false&amp;headers=false&amp;chrome=false&amp;range=A1%3AB19" height="410" width="100%" ></iframe>
```

*make sure to add ; after amp*

**If you want embed editable sheet then follow** [How to embed specific editable cells from a google sheet into a site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65678620/how-to-embed-specific-editable-cells-from-a-google-sheet-into-a-site/72327694#72327694)

Comment: If `&amp;` meaning is not clear have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084237/what-is-amp-used-for

Comment: @xonya Thanks for adding it. I just avoided it! One request, only if my answers solve this problem can I get Up - .vote. As I'm new and not able to perform certain imp. things,  I just want it to reach 50 then I will be able to do all I wanted.