# How to embed specific editable cells from a google sheet into a site

Tags: html, google-sheets, iframe, dropdown, embed

I want to embed my google sheet into a web page

[Click here to go to Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_Rn6ffcE8r-8nVcmH767a8fUfbxJLw-k4CbT-grWqsw/edit?usp=sharing)

I want only to embed the cells C5:D6 as follow (without any other blank cells, the menu,header,sheet toggle at the bottom);
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdImj.jpg)

as the cells are data validations with a dropdown cell,it should be able to edit after the embeding

therefore my Embeding should be
Editable &
Cropped to the specific cells

Answer (score 1):

-Direct answer-

Step 1: Make  an editable sheet for embedding in your site by following these steps https://www.localwebstrategies.com/post/how-to-embed-editable-google-sheets-in-website

Step 2: Follow this short guide to know different inline iframe functions to remove the header, sheet1, sheet2, etc [Display specific sheet with edit mode in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593357/display-specific-sheet-with-edit-mode-in-iframe)

Step 3: Add a custom range like you want A1:C1 then add the formula taken from above (step 2 link) range=A1%3AC1

*don't change this %3A

Step 4: Compile code and get it done like

```
<iframe height="400" width="100%" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16nPYzT2lM1NRyfXgUUJ9_MkNHuSocp8/edit?usp=drivesdk?rm=minimal&amp;single=false&amp;widget=false&amp;headers=false&amp;chrome=false&amp;rangle=A1%3AC1"> </iframe>
```

Replace scr=...[Link].... ? With your link, it will work fine, but only if you are looking to publish all workbook, if you want to publish only one sheet then the link will be a little different and "true" will come on the place of single=false&amp

Comment: This does not produce a result as requested by OP.  Row Numbers and Column Letters appear in the embed produced from your example.