# Pull single cell data from Google Sheets into HTML

Tags: html, google-sheets

I'm attempting to pull some budgeting info from a Google Sheets table into HTML plain text. I'm not even sure if this is possible but it would be great if anyone knew anything about this topic.

I've got no code to display because I'm not at all sure where to start.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As told in detail there about something similar to your question [Display specific sheet with edit mode in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593357/display-specific-sheet-with-edit-mode-in-iframe/72327238#72327238)

I would like to tell you that you can do this and even with live data too.

You just have to go to your sheet > File > Share > Publish to web > then embed code > copy code and paste to your site

Then add the below code to your code.

```
rangle=A1%3AB19
```

For selecting data of a specific range (A1 and B19 is a range, so change them accordingly, but don't change "%3A" in it, as it works as : this symbol here, if you use: it will show an error.

As you are new, so I will give you a sample.

```
<iframe height="410" width="100%" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQrvFsPs7Fpkaao0XvwIUc54WwPsQ4zzlyaEYV6-4JsSEfgZA4YLJpTwlA1pgurUvVCxRzBQ_8OqFJa/pubhtml?  
  gid=1273789&amp; widget=false&amp; range=A1%3AB19"> </iframe>
```

1. Scr="https:// .....link of your sheet till...... ;widget
2. Height, weight, Widget, range etc explained in above-posted thread.