# Javascript manipulate HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like this:

`<!-- Offer Conversion: godaddy --> <iframe src="http://example.go2cloud.org/aff_l?offer_id=90" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="1" height="1"></iframe> <!-- // End Offer Conversion -->
 godaddy`

Now I wanna to toggle some parameter into `src` attribute based on a javascript  event.

[please see the JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ytvvLe3s/5/)

Comment: @gaetanoM fiddle seems fine to me

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Yes, the link now works. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

To manipulate HTML in string create empty element and set it's content with string. Later do what you want.

```js
var string = '<!-- Offer Conversion: godaddy --> <iframe src="http://example.go2cloud.org/usr_l?offer_id=90" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="1" height="1"></iframe> <!-- // End Offer Conversion -->';

$('input').change(function() {
  var content = $('<div>');
  content.html(string);
  var iFrameSrc = content.find('iframe').attr('src');

  if ($('#e1').is(':checked')) {
      iFrameSrc += '&e1='+$('#e1').val();
  }

  if ($('#e2').is(':checked')) {
      iFrameSrc += '&e2='+$('#e2').val();
  }
    content.find('iframe').attr('src', iFrameSrc);

  $('#result').show().text(content.html().replace(/&amp;/g, '&'));
});
```

```css
#result {
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: #dcfffb;
  color: #044f47;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: monospace !important;
  text-align: left;
  direction: ltr;
  border: 1px dotted #9dd3cd;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="e1" type="checkbox" value="someValue1"/>
  <label for="e1">firstParam</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input id="e2" type="checkbox" value="someValue2"/>
  <label for="e2">secondParam</label>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: what is `amp;` ? I don't need it.

Comment: &amp; is the character reference for "An ampersand". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084237/what-is-amp-used-for

Comment: I only need `&`, How can I do this?

Comment: @mohammad Simply replace `&amp;` to `&`