# copy from help code but when try to use gave mistake

Tags: excel, vba

the code I copied is:

```
With Worksheets(1).Range("e5").AddComment
 .Visible = False
 .Text "reviewed on " &amp; Date
End With
```

when debugging in 3th line gave me syntax mistake. Well this is MS help place and it's supposed to work. My version Excel is Office365   so supposed to be often actualized on windows 10 64 ...  any suggestion?
I copied this code from https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.comment

Comment: Guys I don't think he deserved the down vote since the actual code is a direct copy from the link he provided. I mean sure if your experienced you can see the mistake straight away but if your just learning and the documentations says that...

Comment: `Well this is MS help place and it's supposed to work.` Even I used to think that :D Unfortunately it is not true. In this case however the reason is different

Comment: @SiddharthRout I can see from your answer that you checked the link :). Anyway yes MS was also made by humans and humans make mistakes :).

Comment: Well as a rookie you sometimes don't know what to look/google for. So really assuming "no research effort" and down-voting here is a bit hard, isn't it? He researched the official docs and posted the shortest code to reproduce the issue telling which error he got. That's more than many other people here did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That webpage is using an incompatible `code widget.`

Replace `&amp;` with `&`.

`&amp;` is the html code for `&`

```
With Worksheets(1).Range("e5").AddComment
    .Visible = False
    .Text "reviewed on " & Date
End With
```

Comment: Rout, thanks for your comprehension and help. I'm a real rookie

Comment: Being rookie is not a problem. Not doing research is another. You will only attract downvotes like this :) If I was a rookie then I would do a google search on `&amp;` which leads to [Stackoverflow site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084237/what-is-amp-used-for)

Comment: Sidddarth   I undertand you, I start using pc's in 1993 when all was done with dos commands and    buy books to understand ... programs in old raw basic   and made many tries... now at times I forget that google has  this huge power   ... thanks   a lot

Comment: Siddhath Rout - Finlly I tried and arrived to do my idea ... maybe you can gave some advice