# How to scrape non HTML tags using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scarpe data from a website that has a tag as `<a&#32;href="https: evisa.mfa.am ">` for example, look at this [website](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm)

Is there any way in BeautifulSoup to extract data from non html tags?

here's a snippet of the whole html page from the above link

```html
<br/>2.&#32;Airlines&#32;must&#32;provide&#32;advance&#32;passenger&#32;information&#32;of&#32;scheduled&#32;arrival&#32;of&#32;nationals&#32;of&#32;Antigua&#32;and&#32;Barbuda&#32;and&#32;resident&#32;diplomats.&#32;<br/><br/><b>ARGENTINA</b>&#32;-&#32;published&#32;02.04.2020&#32;<br/>Passengers&#32;are&#32;not&#32;allowed&#32;to&#32;enter&#32;Argentina&#32;until&#32;12&#32;April&#32;2020.<br/><br/><b>ARMENIA</b>&#32;-&#32;published&#32;22.03.2020&#32;<br/>1.&#32;Nationals&#32;of&#32;China&#32;(People's&#32;Rep.)&#32;with&#32;a&#32;normal&#32;passport&#32;are&#32;no&#32;longer&#32;visa&#32;exempt.&#32;<br/>2.&#32;Nationals&#32;of&#32;Iran&#32;can&#32;no&#32;longer&#32;obtain&#32;a&#32;visa&#32;on&#32;arrival.&#32;They&#32;must&#32;obtain&#32;a&#32;visa&#32;or&#32;an&#32;e-visa&#32;prior&#32;to&#32;their&#32;arrival&#32;in&#32;Armenia.&#32;The&#32;e-visa&#32;can&#32;be&#32;obtained&#32;at&#32;<a&#32;href="https://evisa.mfa.am/">https://evisa.mfa.am/</a>&#32;<br/>3.&#32;Passengers&#32;who&#32;have&#32;been&#32;in&#32;Austria,&#32;Belgium,&#32;China&#32;(People's&#32;Rep.),&#32;Denmark,&#32;France,&#32;Germany,&#32;Iran,&#32;Italy,&#32;Japan,&#32;Korea&#32;(Rep.),&#32;Netherlands,&#32;Norway,&#32;Spain,&#32;Sweden,&#32;Switzerland&#32;or&#32;United&#32;Kingdom&#32;in&#32;the&#32;past&#32;14&#32;days&#32;are&#32;not&#32;allowed&#32;to&#32;enter&#32;Armenia.<br/>-&#32;This&#32;does&#32;not&#32;apply&#32;to&#32;nationals&#32;or&#32;residents&#32;of&#32;Armenia.<br/>-&#32;This&#32;does&#32;not&#32;apply&#32;to&#32;spouses&#32;or&#32;children&#32;of&#32;nationals&#32;of&#32;Armenia.<br/>-&#32;This&#32;does&#32;not&#32;apply&#32;to&#32;employees&#32;of&#32;foreign&#32;diplomatic&#32;missions&#32;and&#32;consular&#32;institutions.<br/>-&#32;This&#32;does&#32;not&#32;apply&#32;to&#32;representations&#32;of&#32;official&#32;international&#32;missions&#32;or&#32;organizations.<br/>4.&#32;Nationals&#32;of&#32;Armenia&#32;who&#32;have&#32;been&#32;in&#32;Austria,&#32;Belgium,&#32;China&#32;(People's&#32;Rep.),&#32;Denmark,&#32;France,&#32;Germany,&#32;Iran,&#32;Italy,&#32;Japan,&#32;Korea&#32;(Rep.),&#32;Netherlands,&#32;Norway,&#32;Spain,&#32;Sweden,&#32;Switzerland&#32;or&#32;United&#32;Kingdom&#32;in&#32;the&#32;past&#32;14&#32;days&#32;must&#32;undergo&#32;14-days&#32;of&#32;quarantine&#32;or&#32;self-isolation&#32;regime.
```

Comment: please provide an example of input and expected output !

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I have added a small snippet of the html code which contains a non html tag in it, but it you still prefer to look at the whole html page source, you can refer to the link of the website in the question

Comment: check below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called `AMP` chars, you can have a look [here](http://www.amp-what.com/) to understand what it is.

Don't use `html.parser`. Just use a real `parser` such as `lxml` or `html5lib`

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get(
    "https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')


print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: will I then have to install `html5lib` parser lib? If so, how?

Comment: I updated my accepted answer as @ Philip 's approach also did the trick, but it returned everything as text while @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη 's approach lets it be a soup object which can be later used to further parse the other tags. But thanks to you both :)

Comment: one quick question though, how do you know whether it should be parsed by reguler `html.parser` or `html5lib` ?

Comment: @AmanSingh That's according to the website structure, and `html5lib` is well known to escape `AMP` chars. [check](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)

Answer (score 1):

If you parse the webpage using `requests` remove the part of the tag that is wrong, you can pass that to BeautifulSoup.

In the following I'm replacing `&#32;` because it is just a [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) representation of a space.

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm'

response = requests.get(url)
content = response.text.replace('&#32;',' ')

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
```

now you can use BeautifulSoup as you use too.

Comment: thank you so much, i had never come across such a html tag, it was a learning, thanks once again

Comment: That answer is invalid at all. How about if there's multiple escape characters ? what you will do? just will replace every single char ?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη. It's not exactly an invalid answer at all, as it actually does what OP is asking for. When I looked through the HTML of the website i noticed this pattern and tested it. Had there been additional problems I would not have suggested my solution. Are there other ways to do this - definitely and yours looks great too.

Comment: @Philip Well, the `OP` just giving you an example from the data which he's dealing with. so he will not came with every single char of `AMP` and ask you how to escape it. you will not manually replace each char. even when you will work on scraping multiple pages where the AMP is different on each page. so in this case, `Technically` you will have to avoid all of them automatically. and also that part `looks like the site has added to avoid scraping` sounds in wrong direction.

Comment: @Philip here's a side note for why [AMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084237/what-is-amp-used-for) is used within `HTML`

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη. You are right about that, however, I checked what was returned after my replacement, and it worked as a regular soup, which was why I considered it to be fine. I updated that part after checking my assumption. I did not know about the `html5lib` parser, and are unable to install it at my computer, but I will check it out - thanks for that gem :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to analyse your html code before post questions .

Now Try to get your URL

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("test.html","r") as f:
    page = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    url = soup.findAll("a&#32;href=\"https:")
    print(url)
```

Comment: there's nothing new in your approach, nothing that i didn't try. This doesn't help

Comment: test.html is your page i have download it and i have parse all betwen tags you must do some functions like Split() and strip() somthing to get your URL Clear