# Published Google Sheet not showing in embedded iframe

Tags: google-sheets, iframe

I have published a Google Sheet and have modified the iframe embedded on my website to show a certain range of cells only. I am pretty sure the modification has been done correctly, yet when the iframe is embedded, I am getting the error seen in the screenshot [Google Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pazn8.png). The iframe used is the following:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/xxxxx-1vTvQphG_8AomL4TacudrbUYMRlWuL_nITRnPMBeVEOz8bJ6y-3DXFdCqmZ7io9wgyvi6eEBl7Dju2qT/pubhtml?gid=1922308330$amp;widget=true&amp;headers=true&amp;chrome=false&amp;range=A1:B1" style="border:1px solid gray;" width="500" height="600"></iframe>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `$` between gid and amp in the link, it should be `&`

Change your code from:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/xxxxx-1vTvQphG_8AomL4TacudrbUYMRlWuL_nITRnPMBeVEOz8bJ6y-3DXFdCqmZ7io9wgyvi6eEBl7Dju2qT/pubhtml?gid=1922308330$amp;widget=true&amp;headers=true&amp;chrome=false&amp;range=A1:B1" style="border:1px solid gray;" width="500" height="600"></iframe>
```

**To:**

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/xxxxx-1vTvQphG_8AomL4TacudrbUYMRlWuL_nITRnPMBeVEOz8bJ6y-3DXFdCqmZ7io9wgyvi6eEBl7Dju2qT/pubhtml?gid=1922308330&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=true&amp;chrome=false&amp;range=A1:B1" style="border:1px solid gray;" width="500" height="600"></iframe>
```

### Reference:

- [What is &amp used for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9084259/14606052)

Comment: Pondering over this to the point of driving myself crazy. What a foolish error! Thank you for giving me back my sanity.