# Can I use unencoded ampersands (&) in html?

Tags: html, html-entities, ampersand

I'm building a website where I have to work with less then perfect masterdata (I guess I'm not the only one :-))

In my case I have to render an xml filte to html (using xsl).  Sometimes the masterdata is using html-enitites allready (eg ;`&eacute;` in french words) so there I have to use 'disable-output-escaping='yes') there in order to avoid double encoding.

The easiest solution is disable output escaping all together, so I never run the risk of a double encoding.

The only characters that misses encoding for this masterdata are the ampersands.  But when I parse them 'raw' (so rather & than `&amp;` all browsers seem to be ok with it.

So the question : what are the consequenses of using not encoded ampersands in html?

Comment: You have a really awkward situation to deal with - my sympathies. Can you preprocess the master data before the XSL transformation? You could replace any bare ampersands with `&amp;`, using a simple regexp, so normalising the input before it gets to the XSL.

Comment: @Peter it's possible these days for an asker to unilaterally self-close a question as a duplicate. I suggest doing so.

Comment: @Mark I got notified of your comment, I think the status is ok now?

Comment: @Peter yep, looks good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK bare ampersands are illegal in HTML. With that out of the way, let's look at the consequences:

- You are now relying on the browser's capabilities to detect and gracefully recover from the problem. Note that in order to do this, the browser has to *guess*: `&`  is "clearly" an ampersand followed by a space, and `&copy;` is clearly the copyright symbol. But what about the text fragment `edit&copy`? The browser I 'm using right now mangles it.
- If you are using XHTML, or if the content is ever going to be inserted into an XML document, the result will be a hard parser error.

Since it's more difficult to detect and account for these cases manually than it is to replace all ampersands that are not part of entities (say with a regex), you should really do the latter.

Comment: the browser does not have to *guess* as there is a spec for that, at least in HTML5

Answer (score 8):

**It depends**

The best research I have seen on this topic can be found [here](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/ambiguous-ampersands)

In HTML5 you should escape all of the ampersands that do not fall in the categories below:

> An ambiguous ampersand is a U+0026 AMPERSAND character (&) that is
>   followed by one or more characters in the range U+0030 DIGIT ZERO (0)
>   to U+0039 DIGIT NINE (9), U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A to U+007A LATIN
>   SMALL LETTER Z, and U+0041 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A to U+005A LATIN
>   CAPITAL LETTER Z, followed by a U+003B SEMICOLON character (;), where
>   these characters do not match any of the names given in the named
>   character references section.

Comment: Matthias Bynens, the author of the linked post, is a formidable and highly active developer. Any interesting question you have about the edge cases of the HTML, ECMAScript and CSS specs, there's a significant chance Matthias has written about it in pedantic detail, as he has done here.

Answer (score 4):

See [Do I really need to encode '&' as '&amp;'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493405/do-i-really-need-to-encode-as-amp)

To summarize: Yes you can, but strictly speaking it is  not legal (except in HTML5 where it is legal as long as it doesn't "look like" a character entity).