# html query string, get style request

Tags: html, query-string

In a php file I typically generate links like this:

```
<a href="admin.php?t=email&id=3">Edit Primary Email</a>
```

When I look at this in FireFox's "View Source" window, I notice it highlights it in red, and says "& did not start a character reference", which is true, but is this valid for a query string? It still works (and gets rid of the 'error') if I change it to `&amp`; but I'm curious now about the official way it should be (which I think is the first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox and you are both right.

A query string indeed uses `&` to separate parameters - but the *HTML document* requires ampersands to be encoded `&amp;`.

See [Do I really need to encode '&' as '&amp;'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493405/do-i-really-need-to-encode-as-amp) for more background.

Answer (score 1):

> but is this valid for a query string?

For a query string by itself? No.

For a query string expressed in HTML? Yes.

This is the latter.