# URL parameters not passing HTML5 validation

Tags: html, w3c-validation

Here's the website:
http://prodontic.com/cs2/index.php?q=conscience-statements&record=8

Here's the W3C validation report:
http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fprodontic.com%2Fcs2%2Findex.php%3Fq%3Dconscience-statements%26record%3D8&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices

This does not validate but the validator does not give any indication about how to build URLs with parameters.

This has to be simple but I can't seem to figure it out.... what I am missing?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Simply replace `&` in your URLs that you have in your HTML with `&amp;`.

So for instance, replace

```
<a href='index.php?q=conscience-statements&record=7'>&laquo;</a>
```

with

```
<a href='index.php?q=conscience-statements&amp;record=7'>&laquo;</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You say: `but the validator does not give any indication about how to build URLs with parameters`

That's weird, W3C's error-description (repeatedly) clearly states:
`& probably should have been escaped as &amp;`

Also, have a look at this answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3493425/588079

Hope that helps!