# Bootstrap - Chosen plugin: & in Text changes to &amp;

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-chosen

I am using Twitter Bootstrap v2.1.1 with the Chosen plugin that comes with it v0.9.8
and am experiencing a weird issue where if my select contains ampersands like "Tom & Jerry" and I do a search for "m", the text in the Chosen select changes the "&" to "&" and the "m" in the "&" is selected.

Here is a JSFiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/yakitori/2pszc/

```
$('#chz-select').chosen({search_contains:true});
```

Even though the Chosen plugin came with Bootstrap, seems like there's some weird conflict.
If I remove the bootstrap.min.js from the JSFiddle, the "&" doesn't get converted and the search works fine. Anyone else experiencing this issue? Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Chosen comes with Bootstrap? Bootstrap has its own typeahead and dropowns. In any case. Select2 is a more advanced fork of Chosen. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I'd switch to Select2, a fork of Chosen which has a much better API:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/2pszc/1/

```
$('#chz-select').select2();
```

Comment: This looks promising, I'll check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, **remove `search_contains:true` make it `search_contains:false`**.  Hope you do not need 'contains' search.

```
$('#chz-select').chosen({search_contains:false});
```

or simply have

```
$('#chz-select').chosen();
```

With reference to this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3493425/1671639), better **encode your & symbol using `&amp;` in your HTML**.

Here is your html encoded `&` with `&amp;`

```
<select id="chz-select" data-placeholder="Select...">
    <option value="1">Tom &amp; Jerry</option>
    <option value="2">Andy &amp; Jamie</option>
    <option value="3">Mark &amp; Amy</option>
</select>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2pszc/2/)

Comment: Thanks for this but unfortunately we need the search_contains:true.