# Javascript &amp; doesn't append next parameter value pair

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing

I am trying to append multiple parameter value pairs to a url for an ajax request. I know that this is supposed to be done using &amp; instead of &. Why then, does the first function work and the second one fails?

```
function accountByName(firstName, lastName, resultRegion) {
    var baseAddress = "Bank";
    var data = "firstName=" + getValue(firstName) + "&lastName=" + getValue(lastName);
    var address = baseAddress + "?" + data;
    ajaxResult(address, resultRegion);
}

function accountByName(firstName, lastName, resultRegion) {
    var baseAddress = "Bank";
    var data = "firstName=" + getValue(firstName) + "&amp;lastName=" + getValue(lastName);
    var address = baseAddress + "?" + data;
    ajaxResult(address, resultRegion);
}
```

When I do print statements in the serverside java code the firstName variable prints fine, but the lastName variable always comes back null when I use &amp; Both variables print fine when I just use &, but I know this is not correct XML.

Comment: Why would you expect "&amp;" to work?  I don't understand. URL syntax has nothing to do with HTML syntax.

Comment: `I know that this is supposed to be done using &amp; instead of &` Wherever you read that - it's wrong.

Comment: I think I may have over complicated this. My instructor stated "If you have an "&" in a URL in xhtml, you are required to
replace it with "&amp;" Which made me think I needed to use &amp; though I'd never done so before. I think now that he meant for when it needs to be parsed as XML, not as a url. I poked around and did find examples of people using &amp; in urls, so I thought just using & must be incorrect. I think those examples must have just been non-functional code.

Comment: Something you should wonder about is whether it makes any sense to be working on learning xhtml (as opposed to HTML5) in the modern world.

Comment: @Pointy See Adam's answer and the link in my response there for why you still need to know this even in HTML5.

Comment: @sage88 oh yes I agree with that part; my comment was intended more generally than this particular question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's what your instructor meant:

In an (X)HTML page if you have something like:

`<a href="http://example.com/?query=string&with=parameters">Link</a>`

You should use (even though it really doesn't make a difference except to the validator)

`<a href="http://example.com/?query=string&amp;with=parameters">Link</a>`

That is the **ONLY** time you should use an `&amp;` in a query string.

Comment: This was what I needed to clear things up. As to your comment above regarding why would anyone bother with xhtml when html5 exists, I don't think it's a valid comment given the above example. In html5 you're still supposed to use the &amp; when doing the above. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493405/do-i-really-need-to-encode-as-amp

Comment: @sage88 - that wasn't my comment.

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrect: you are **not** supposed to use `&amp;` as the parameter separator in a URL. The first function constructs the URL:

```
Bank?firstName=foo&lastName=bar
```

The second:

```
Bank?firstName=foo&amp;lastName=bar
```

The 1st URL has two parameters: `firstName` and `lastName` with the values `foo` and `bar`.

The 2nd URL has two parameters: `firstName` and `amp;lastName` with the values `foo` and `bar`. (Note: I believe the second parameter name is invalid and am not sure how it'd be parsed in Java; it may be library/server dependent)

Your Java code fails printing the `lastName` parameter in the second case because in that case it is not set.

Your confusion seems to stem from a misunderstanding of the URL format. The URL format is unrelated to XML or HTML. It is completely separate from the two. `&amp;` is an XML/HTML entity. Were the URL some form of XML, you would be correct. However, as it is not one should not expect it to follow the rules and standards of XML.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I think that Adam's helped me clear up my confusion more on why you'd ever use &amp;. Thanks, this still helped!

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a URL, not some XML content. You have to think about what system is going to be paying attention. An XML/HTML parser is never going to look at that URL you're creating. The server, however, will certainly be interested in interpreting the URL as a URL. The XML entity syntax `&amp;` is completely alien to something parsing a URL.