# Difference between single and double equals in Slim (= vs ==)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

In Slim, when should I use double equals sign?

For example:

```
== yield
== render 'partial'
== stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all"
title == full_title(yield(:title))

- flash.each do |key, value|
    == value
```

or

```
= yield
= render 'partial'
= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all"
title == full_title(yield(:title))

- flash.each do |key, value|
    = value
```

Comment: code escape, so as far as I remember double equal disables the html escape

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ When do I need to disable HTML escape?

Comment: when, you try to insert already rendered text, for example when you rendered it manually

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. `=` inserts HTML with escaped characters. Example:

   ```
   = javascript_include_tag("1", "2")
   ```
2. `==` inserts HTML without escaping. It is needed when you have already rendered HTML and you need to insert it to your layout directly. Example:

   ```
   == render 'footer'
   ```

Answer (score 13):

From the [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#Output__):

> **Output =**
>
> The equal sign tells Slim it's a Ruby call that produces output to add to the buffer.
>
> **Output without HTML escaping ==**
>
> Same as the single equal sign (=), but does not go through the escape_html method.

Update regarding HTML escaping:

First of all, what "html escape" means is this:

```
puts html_escape('is a > 0 & a < 10?')
# => is a &gt; 0 &amp; a &lt; 10?
```

Then, some reading about why/when you want to do it:

- [Do I really need to encode '&' as '&amp;'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493405/do-i-really-need-to-encode-as-amp)
- http://text-symbols.com/html/encode/
- http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp