# When editing html in VS2013, I want to be able to type & [ampersand space] without getting &Aacute. How can I set that?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

When editing an html file in VS2013, when I type an ampersand followed by a space, the editor automatically gives me &Aacute instead of just &. Is there a way to turn this off with high granularity? I don't want to disable the autotype feature entirely (at least, not yet). But this one is (in my opinion) ridiculous, since I don't ever use &Aacute (it's not a common character in English, to say the least).

Comment: You should not type an & in an HTML file, but its entity &amp; - if the problem arises in a code block inside your html, you can stop the intellisense suggestion pressing ESC when the suggestion box is shown.

Comment: I should type &amp instead of & because... ?? I wonder why, when I type <, the list that appears does NOT pre-select the first entry (<a), but when I type & (before pressing the space) the first entry (&Aacute) IS pre-selected. If I could get the latter to act like the former I'd be happy.

Comment: Because your HTML would (probably, if not HTML5) be out of specification. Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493405/do-i-really-need-to-encode-as-amp and its comments for a more detailed explanation. IntelliSense in VS tries to guess what you are going to write and select it if it thinks it has enough confidence in its suggestion; as I said, press ESC to dismiss the suggestion before pressing the space bar.

Comment: @Alex, thanks for that link -- informative.