# Using a "&" in <a></a>

Tags: html

Currently, I have:

```
<a href="process.php?action=start&pid=1">Start Process</a>
```

However, I ran this code through the W3 HTML validator (https://validator.w3.org), and it comes up with this:

```
& did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as &amp;.)
```

Is there another proper way to put a "&" into an `<a></a>` tag, or should I just leave it like how it is?

Comment: Probably check earlier code

Comment: AFAIK, You should use ASCII code `&amp;` instead of just `&`. Though I haven't seen any difference, I believe that some fonts doesn't support special characters. At that time you will not be able to see `&`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I really need to encode '&' as '&amp;'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493405/do-i-really-need-to-encode-as-amp)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Handling ampersands (`&`) in URLs is explained in the [Web Design Group](http://www.htmlhelp.com/)'s [Common Validator Problems page](http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html):

> **Ampersands (&'s) in URLs**
>
> Another common error occurs when including a URL which contains an ampersand ("&"):
>
> ```
> <!-- This is invalid! --> <a href="foo.cgi?chapter=1&section=2&copy=3&lang=en">...</a>
> ```
>
> This example generates an error for "unknown entity section" because the "&" is assumed to begin an entity reference. Browsers often recover safely from this kind of error, but real problems do occur in some cases. In this example, many browsers correctly convert &copy=3 to ©=3, which may cause the link to fail. Since `&lang;` is the HTML entity for the left-pointing angle bracket, some browsers also convert &lang=en to 〈=en. And one old browser even finds the entity &sect;, converting &section=2 to §ion=2.
>
> To avoid problems with both validators and browsers, always use `&amp;` in place of & when writing URLs in HTML:
>
> ```
> <a href="foo.cgi?chapter=1&amp;section=2&amp;copy=3&amp;lang=en">...</a>
> ```
>
> Note that replacing & with `&amp;` is only done when writing the URL in HTML, where "&" is a special character (along with "<" and ">"). When writing the same URL in a plain text email message or in the location bar of your browser, you would use "&" and not `"&amp;"`. With HTML, the browser translates `"&amp;"` to "&" so the Web server would only see "&" and not `"&amp;"` in the query string of the request.