# How escaping is safe?

Tags: html

In the various answers in the SO, it is mentioned that you should escape ampersand, greater than and less than symbols. Even &ndash and &mdash should be escaped as far I understood.

Source: [Do I really need to encode '&' as '&amp;'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493405/do-i-really-need-to-encode-as-amp), check out the answers in there!

Can anyone show me how exactly security can be breached or cookie stealing can happen if I do not escape the symbols I have mentioned. It does not make sense to me the people can hack the websites because of this.

Comment: Please downvote by mentioning the reason :(

Comment: I didn't downvote you ... but what the heck are you talking about?  Could you please cite a reference link that says "you should escape ampersand"?  To give us some context in which that statement was made?

Comment: haha, alright! That's what I have thought "what the heck". Let me put a link in there

Comment: Read the answers, they gave generic replies on why one should escape.  They said cookie stealing and all .. can you check

Comment: *"Read the answers, they gave generic replies..."* - @Mahesh: Perhaps you did not read that thread thoroughly enough. Did you see this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3493425/1355315 ?

Comment: This is fundamentally not a security issue. It's a matter of writing validating HTML, and avoiding possible anomalies in how your HTML behaves. The link you yourself cite provides all the information you could possibly want about the issue.

Comment: @abhi " which is a huge problem for user-submitted data, which could very well lead to HTML and script injection, cookie stealing and other exploits." regarding this .. I'm talking about. It's in the answer you have mentioned

Comment: @Mahesh: That line is prefixed with *"you might also not be escaping tag delimiters..."*. That is out of context from ampersand thingy.

Comment: oh alright! Thanks for the info

Comment: @Mahesh: Also regarding the security on script injection, that answer talks about other things. For example, you could get data which contains `<script>` tags with malicious javascript inside. You should be escaping such data before displaying on your web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is "should I always use `&amp;`  (and never "&") - then yes.

If for no other reason than "good style".

Here's why:

- [HTML: Do I really need to encode '&' as '&'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493405/do-i-really-need-to-encode-as-amp).
- [Why should the '&' (ampersand) character be HTML escaped?](https://www.quora.com/Why-should-the-ampersand-character-be-HTML-escaped)

HTML comes from [SGML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language), and SGML/HTML have a notion of ["entities"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SGML_entity), which are delimited in SGML text by "&" .. ";".

The ampersand character `&` is must be defined as an entity, to differentiate it from the start of an entity.  So must HTML brackets `<` and `>` (`&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively).  And so on.

Other HTML entities are simply defined for "convenience", such as `&copy;` or `&euro;`.

Here is a complete list of W3C-conforming, HTML5 entities:

- http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

PS:

As torazaburo noted above, "this is not fundamentally a security issue".  It's merely the way HTML works ;)