# Thymeleaf parsing error due to link with &

Tags: spring, url, thymeleaf

My link:

```
<a data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-color="white" data-pin-
count="beside" href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?

url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com%2Fphotos%2Fkentbrew%2F6851755809%2F
&media=https%3A%2F%2Ffarm8.staticflickr.com%2F7027%2F6851755809_df5b2051c9_z.jpg
&description=Next%20stop%3A%20Pinterest">
<img src="https://assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pinit_fg_en_rect_white_20.png" />
</a>
```

Currently thymeleaf thinks that the & in the url should be followed by an ';' character.

Exception message:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The reference to entity "media" must end with the ';' delimiter.
```

Is there any way to get rid of the & signs and still have a functional url? Or is there any way to tell thyemleaf to 'overlook' the & signs in the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `&` you should use the entity `&amp;` to encode your url like:

```
href="www.myurl.com?param1=value&amp;param2=value"
```

Or build it using [Link URL Expression](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#standard-expression-syntax) `@{...}` with parameters:

```
th:href="@{www.myurl.com(param1=${'value1'},param2=${'value2'})}"
```

It's not only a Thymeleaf matter. You can find a detailed explanation here: [Do I really need to encode `&` as `&amp;`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493405/do-i-really-need-to-encode-as-amp))

Comment: Thank you kind sir