# Special character encoding not working? (&amp;)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, special-characters

I've have tried to encode the `&` like so `&amp;`. However, when I tried this it did not fix it in my title like I'm reading it should on Stackoverflow. Just to be clear my page title still says `Plan &amp; Billing` in the browser and In my code I have `Plan &amp; Billing`. Why is the encoding not working? (p.s. it works with other special characters)

HTML:

```
 <% page_title 'Plan &amp; Billing • My Account' %>
```

This question is unique to any other I have found because I'm asking "Why my encoding is not working", where as, suggested duplicates only say "Why you need them for encoding".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I really need to encode '&' as '&amp;'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493405/do-i-really-need-to-encode-as-amp)

Comment: Strings need to be made `html_safe`.

Comment: @liam His question was why do you need it. Mine is why does it not work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your string should be made `html_safe`:

```
<% page_title 'Plan &amp; Billing • My Account'.html_safe %>
```

You can also use the `sanitize` method:

```
<% page_title sanitize('Plan &amp; Billing • My Account') %>
```