# HTML tag auto encoding from text to UTF-8 in Struts2 tags

Tags: jsp, encoding, struts2, struts-tags

I have some problem with auto encoding from text to UTF-8 in Struts2 tag.

I want to pass a value witch contain a HTML tag from action class to JSP page, but in Struts tag this value is automatically encoding to UTF-8 and HTML tag is not correct displayed.

For example:
I have a String variable named `param` in action class

```
String param=param[0] + "& <br>" + param[1];
```

And this `param` is pass in JSP page and displayed in page using Struts tag:

```
<s:property value="%{param}">
```

My problem is that, in JSP page, `<br>` tag is encoding automatically and displeyed like  `&ltbr&gt` instead using it  like a HTML tag.

Does anyone have any idea how I could skip this automatically encoding process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the ([documented](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/property-tag.html)) attribute `escapeHtml`?

```
<s:property value="%{param}" escapeHtml="false" />
```

PS: Two additional notes:

1. You are using the character `&`, which is special in HTML . If you are not going to escape the string, you [should write it as `&amp;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493405/do-i-really-need-to-encode-as-amp)
2. As Rowan C aptly points out in his answer, using unescaped html in a web page can be dangerous, especially if the string (in your case the `param` array) is dynamic and can be set by the client. If you can't trust or properly sanitize it, then don't do that. Seriously.

Answer (score 1):

The [`s:property` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/property-tag.html) escapes the html code by default to prevent XSS security violation. If you trust the content you display with this tag then you can use one of the `escape` attribtes to disable this process:

```
Name                Required    Default Evaluated   Type    Description
escapeCsv           false       false   false       Boolean Whether to escape CSV (useful to escape a value for a column)
escapeHtml          false       true    false       Boolean Whether to escape HTML
escapeJavaScript    false       false   false       Boolean Whether to escape Javascript
escapeXml           false       false   false       Boolean Whether to escape XML
```

In your code you can use

```
<s:property value="%{param}" escapeHtml="false"/>
```