# How can I write and ampersand in a v-input in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How can I write and ampersand in a v-input in vue?

```
<v-input
   label="Terms"
    description="I agree to <a href='/legal-information/terms-conditions" target="_blank">Terms & Conditions</a>
    type="checkbox"
    :value.sync="registerDetails.terms"
    :v="$v.registerDetails.terms"
 />
```

Comment: & needs to be encoded for HTML, and can be done so using `&amp;`. Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493405/do-i-really-need-to-encode-as-amp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following including using the html code for ampersand as well as correcting usage of single and double quotes:

```
<v-input
   label="Terms"
    description="I agree to <a href='/legal-information/terms-conditions' target='_blank'>Terms &amp; Conditions</a>"
    type="checkbox"
    :value.sync="registerDetails.terms"
    :v="$v.registerDetails.terms"
 />
```

Hopefully that helps!