# What is the valid text node value for my SCORM 1.2 prerequisites?

Tags: xml, manifest, scorm, scorm1.2

I am trying to create a sequenced SCORM 1.2 package with multiple modules in the package. Specifying multiple item identifiers creates invalid XML though.

From ADL's "[The SCORM Content Aggregation Model](http://xml.coverpages.org/SCORM-12-CAM.pdf)" (go to section 2-139), the text node value used is:

```
<adlcp:prerequisites type="aicc_script">R1&R2</adlcp:prerequisites>
```

So the XML chokes on the ampersand between R1/R2. What do I use instead of the ampersand character? I tried a comma which worked in Moodle but not Saba.

My manifest contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest identifier="captivate_test_multires_seq_4" version="1" xmlns="http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2" xmlns:adlcp="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2 imscp_rootv1p1p2.xsd http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsmd_rootv1p2p1 imsmd_rootv1p2p1.xsd http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2 adlcp_rootv1p2.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <schema>ADL SCORM</schema>
        <schemaversion>1.2</schemaversion>
        <lom xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsmd_rootv1p2p1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsmd_rootv1p2p1 imsmd_rootv1p2p1.xsd">
            <general>
                <title>
                <langstring xml:lang="x-none">Captivate Multi-Res Sequenced Test 4</langstring>
                </title>
                <description>
                    <langstring xml:lang="x-none">Captivate Multi-Res Sequenced Test 4</langstring>
                </description>
            </general>
        </lom>
    </metadata>
    <organizations default="kineo_scorm">
        <organization identifier="kineo_scorm">
            <title>Captivate Multi-Res Sequenced Test 4</title>
            <item identifier="item_1" isvisible="true" identifierref="res1">
                <title>Mod 1</title>
                <adlcp:masteryscore>50</adlcp:masteryscore>
            </item>
            <item identifier="item_2" isvisible="true" identifierref="res2">
                <title>Mod 2</title>
                <adlcp:prerequisites type="aicc_script">item_1</adlcp:prerequisites>
                <adlcp:masteryscore>50</adlcp:masteryscore>
            </item>
            <item identifier="item_3" isvisible="true" identifierref="res3">
                <title>Mod 3</title>
                <adlcp:prerequisites type="aicc_script">item1&item_2</adlcp:prerequisites>
                <adlcp:masteryscore>50</adlcp:masteryscore>
            </item>
        </organization>
    </organizations>
    <resources>
        <resource identifier="res1" type="webcontent" href="mod_1/mod_1.htm" adlcp:scormtype="sco">
            <file href="mod_1/mod_1.htm"/>
            <file href="mod_1/mod_1.swf"/>
        </resource>
        <resource identifier="res2" type="webcontent" href="mod_2/mod_2.htm" adlcp:scormtype="sco">
            <file href="mod_2/mod_2.htm"/>
            <file href="mod_2/mod_2.swf"/>
        </resource>
        <resource identifier="res3" type="webcontent" href="mod_3/mod_3.htm" adlcp:scormtype="sco">
            <file href="mod_3/mod_3.htm"/>
            <file href="mod_3/mod_3.swf"/>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using &amp; which is the preferred way of escaping ampersands (See also [How do I escape ampersands in XML so they are rendered as entities in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328538/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-xml))

(I just tried it in a LMS and it worked)

Comment: I'm a step closer now, thanks periklis, the manifest didn't die in a ball of flames, but the SCORM 1.2 sequencing also didn't pick up in Saba as it did in Moodle. I'd say it's something else :/

Comment: if you try using a single prerequisite, does it get through? Also have you tried importing the default multiple SCO from ADL, "Maritime Navigation", to see if Saba supports it?

Comment: Hmm, I couldn't actually find that directly named example - but i did find a bunch of other test packages, including SCORM 2004 sequencing, and a multi-SCO SCORM 1.2 package. Interestingly, Saba failed to comprehend the full-on 2004 sequencing. Also, the SCORM 1.2 "MultipleSCOEx.zip" didn't do anything sequencial, and SCORM Cloud service threw Javascript errors with that example.