# CURL with XML post data issue

Tags: php, parsing, curl, encoding, xml-parsing

I am using CURL-PHP to post data to server. Options are set to curl through curl_setopt function. But somehow anonymous user enters "&" in his password. As data is collected in xml so as Xml's drawback it stops there and fires some XML Exception. 
If i used CDATA then it may not parse that password and ultimately authentication wil be failed. I used php encoding functions like htmlentities,html_entit_decode,utf8_encode,utf8_encode,urlencode nad urldecode. But the issue is same. 
Is there any method to send "&" through XML and posted that data thurh CURL. As per my knowledge, CURL itself internally parses.

Thanks,

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328538/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-xml

Answer (score 0):

First of all ensure that XML string contains `&amp` in password before posting

`(<password>123&amp;</password>` or `<user password="123&amp;"></user>` for `123&amp;`

`htmlentities()` must be applied to $password, nor to $xml_data. Than ensure that it attached to curl request like `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data)`;

Without any additional encodings. It should work! In other cases problem on POST handler side.

Comment: You should update your answer to sth more readable using some ` to hightligh your code.