# how to parse xml with special character? specifically for ampersand

Tags: javascript, xml, special-characters

I am getting data from text box and change it into xml format and store it in data base. For allowing special characters i wrote javascript function to replace special character with its html entities.

```
 "     &quot;
 &     &amp;
 <     &lt;
 >     &gt;
```

for "quotes , less than , greater than" its working fine.  for "&" it is showing xml parser error 
   i used javascript to replace special character with its entity

```
  string.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/'/g, "\\'");

  for "&" allow showing warning but it get stored in data base. please help me to sort out this problem . 


 i begin with string.replace(/&/g, '&amp;') even though i am getting
```

**Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 9: parser error : EntityRef: expecting ';' in /var/www/**
       i tried this also &amp;amp; as mentioned in this link [stackoverflow.com/questions/1328538/…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328538/%E2%80%A6)
    After that there is no warning but while saving in db it saved as "ab &amp cd"

Comment: Once you write parse error, once warning - what's the case now? Can you post the error/warning-message please?

Comment: What database? Where is the JS running (browser? node? soething else?)? Is the JS talking directly to the database or do you have some server side program in between?

Answer (score 6):

*Start* with replacing the `&` character, *then* replace the other characters. Otherwise you will replace `&` from the previous entities (`&lt;` etc.) by `&amp;`

```
string.replace(/&/g, '&amp;amp;') //<= start with
      .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
      .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
      .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
      .replace(/'/g, '&apos');
// &apos; may be "\\'",  depends on how te OP wants to use it
```

[**edit** based on comments] use `&amp;amp;` to replace the ampersand character

Comment: thanks for yr reply. i started with string.replace(/&/g, '&amp;') even though i am getting                                                                    Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 9: parser error : xmlParseEntityRef: no name in /var/www/...                                                                 i tried this also &amp;amp   as mentioned in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328538/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-xml                                                  there is no warning but while saving in db it saved as "ab &amp cd" .

Comment: Would `&amp;amp;` (semicolon added) instead of `&amp;amp` work?

Comment: thanks Yaar.  Even though i am getting same warning :( and while saving in DB it is saving as "ab &amp cd" instead of "ab & cd" . :( no idea to proceed.

Comment: even i use string.replace(/&/g, '&#00038;') instead of "&amp;" it is get saved in database but i am getting ***Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 9: parser error : xmlParseEntityRef: no name in /var/www/**