# cannot parse a url from xml file in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, replace

I'm trying to `parse an xml file` . I'm using the `function downloadUrl` . The element `<link>` of my xml file contains a url with ' & ' ( ampersant character ) . The error in my browser says : **"  Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null   "** I replace the `&` with `&amp;` in a sample file-similar to my xml and the parse runs great!One important information : **I cannot edit my xml file** .
So , the solution is to insert at the javascript code a function to replace  this character `&` with `&amp;` .Something like that i imagine:

```
function htmlEscape(items) {
    return String(items)
            .replace(/&/g, '&amp;');
    }
```

But i cannot find the way on how to do that.
Here's is my script :

```
var infowindow;
      var map;

      function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.822590,24.653320);
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 6,
          center: myLatlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        downloadUrl("moredata.xml", function(doc) {
          var items = doc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("item");
          for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
               var description = items[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].textContent;
                var temp        = items[i].getElementsByTagName("temp")[0].textContent;
                    var title       = items[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].textContent;
            var link        = items[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].textContent;
            var latlng      = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(items[i].getElementsByTagName("glat")[0].textContent),
                                                     parseFloat(items[i].getElementsByTagName("glon")[0].textContent));
```

a part of my xml :

```
<channel>
    <title>
        Real time weather in Greece
    </title>
    <link>http://www.123.gr/</link>
    <image>
    <url>
    http://www.123.gr/templates/metar/images/metar.gif
    </url>
    <title>123.gr</title>
    <link>http://www.123.gr/</link>
    </image>
    <description>
    Real time weather in Greece
    </description>
    <language>el</language>
    <pubDate>Thu, 03 Apr 2014 17:08:10 +0300</pubDate>
    <copyright>123.gr</copyright>
    <managingEditor>kondilis@123.gr</managingEditor>
    <webMaster>admin@123.gr</webMaster>
    <item>
    <title>Center</title>
    <description>Salonica</description>
    <link>
        http://www.metar.gr/index.php?option=com_jumi&fileid=12&Itemid=73&station=1227
    </link>
    <temp>16.7 °C</temp>
    <glat>40.422726139672626</glat>
    <glon>22.93392777442932</glon>
    </item>
</channel>
```

the `downloadUrl` function :

```
function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
 var status = -1;
 var request = createXmlHttpRequest();
 if (!request) {
   return false;
 }

 request.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (request.readyState == 4) {
     try {
       status = request.status;
     } catch (e) {
       // Usually indicates request timed out in FF.
     }
     if (status == 200) {
       callback(request.responseXML, request.status);
       request.onreadystatechange = function() {};
     }
   }
 }
 request.open('GET', url, true);
 try {
   request.send(null);
 } catch (e) {
   changeStatus(e);
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `responseXML` is broken because of an invalid XML document, it's not just an invalid string. You will probably have to retrieve the `responseText`, replace the ampersands with properly encoded entities and then do something like the solutions to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054108/how-to-convert-string-to-xml-object-in-javascript) to make that string into a traversable XML document

Comment: Here is another SO question that deals with replacing the characters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555890/how-to-parse-xml-with-special-character-specifically-for-ampersand

Comment: @jwatts1980. Thanks for the response!I have tried many many times to insert replace , but i didn't have any result.Can you show me the way?

Comment: Rob M.'s answer addresses that.

Comment: So , i have to parse my xml with jquery?

Comment: The answer has two parts, a non-jquery version and a jquery version.

Comment: @Rob.M. I did a parse with jquery , but replace is not working