# How to write an URI string in App.Config

Tags: c#, configuration, windows-services, uri, app-config

I am making a `Windows Service`. The `Service` has to donwload something every night, and therefor I want to place the URI in the App.Config in case I later need to change it.

I want to write an URI in my App.Config. What makes it invalid and how should i approach this?

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="fooUriString" 
         value="https://foo.bar.baz/download/DownloadStream?id=5486cfb8c50c9f9a2c1bc43daf7ddeed&login=null&password=null"/>
</appSettings>
```

My errors:

```
- Entity 'login' not defined
- Expecting ';'
- Entity 'password' not defined
- Application Configuration file "App.config" is invalid. An error occurred
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328538/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-xml just escape the ampersand

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You haven't properly encoded the ampersands in your URI. Remember that `app.config` is an XML file, so you must conform to XML's requirements for escaping (e.g. `&` should be `&amp;`, `<` should be `&lt;` and `>` should be `&gt;`).

In your case, it should look like this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add
        key="fooUriString" 
        value="https://foo.bar.baz/download/DownloadStream?id=5486cfb8c50c9f9a2c1bc43daf7ddeed&amp;login=null&amp;password=null"
    />
</appSettings>
```

But in general, if you wanted to store a string that looked like `"I <3 angle bra<kets & ampersands >>>"` then do this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add
        key="someString"
        value="I &lt;3 angle bra&lt;kets &amp; ampersands &gt;&gt;&gt;"
    />
</appSettings>

void StringEncodingTest() {
    String expected = "I <3 angle bra<kets & ampersands >>>";
    String actual   = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someString"];
    Debug.Assert.AreEqual( expected, actual );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. You were first, so I'll accept yours, in a couple of minuts when the SO gods allow me too.

Answer (score 9):

`&amp;` should work just fine, Wikipedia has a [List of predefined entities in XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML).

Answer (score 8):

Try using: `&amp;` in place of **&** in the url