# Store AzureCosmosDb connection string in web.config

Tags: mongodb, azure, web-config, azure-cosmosdb

I created an AzureCosmosDb account in Azure in order to use MongoDb.

I got a connection string that works perfectly but it ends by `/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb`. So I am unable to store it in the connectionStrings section of my web.config file. It says :

```
Entity 'replicaSet' not defined
Expecting ;
Application Configuration file "Web.config" is invalid. '=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'.
```

I don't want to store it in a constant so is there a way to make it work ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not strip that portion in web.config and just append it via your app? There are no credentials or changing variables in that portion.

Comment: This is not a direct answer but I was able to store your db connection string value as an Azure WebApp setting via the Azure Portal. I have also stored my own pre Cosmos DocumentDb connection string in my own local Web.Config the difference being there is no reference to replicaSet in my string. I wonder if you could simplify your CosmosDb declaration on Azure as a test to avoid the replicaSet portion.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I am not sure appending some text to a connection string was the exact purpose of a connectionstring. I see it has a variable that I can change without editing my code.

Comment: @camelCase I tried to remove the replicaSet but I cannot connect to the DB. Thanks for the Azure setting tip.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`web.config` file is an XML file, so any value has to be a valid XML.

Нou need to replace `&` sign with `&amp;`:

```
/?ssl=true&amp;replicaSet=globaldb
```

Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685846/how-to-write-an-uri-string-in-app-config).