# Xerces parser gives error while parsing XML file containing '&' operator

Tags: xml

Xerces parser gives error while parsing XML file containing '&' operator. Can XML file (UTF-8 encoded) contain '&' operator?

-
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer on this site:

[Escape ampersands in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328538/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-xml)

You can also use CDATA tags too.

```
<![CDATA[My &&&&& ampersands.]]>
```