# PHP function not cleaning my XML file

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml file where am replacing the & with `&amp;` then taking the `&amp;` converting back to & to insert into the database. My script is not replacing the & with `&amp;`.

```
function xml_entities($string) {
return strtr(
    $string, 
    array(
        "&" => "&amp;",
    )
);
}

$content=xml_entities(file_get_contents("http://www.site.com/feeds/xxxx/property.xml"));
file_put_contents("cleanme.xml",$content);
echo "File clean complete".'<br>';
```

Comment: Why not simply `file_put_contents("cleanme.xml", str_replace("&", "&amp;", $content));`?

Comment: i recommend changing '&' to 'and' and then back to "&amp;" for displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$content=file_get_contents("http://www.site.com/feeds/xxxx/property.xml");
file_put_contents("cleanme.xml", str_replace("&", "&amp;", $content));

echo "File clean complete".'<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to have an XML file with unquoted `&` characters. It is considered an invalid XML file (impossible to open for any parser).

Why isn't your feed providing the `&` already in an `&amp;` state?

See: [How do I escape ampersands in XML so they are rendered as entities in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328538/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-xml)