# Java JAK malforming URL

Tags: java, kml, jak

I am using the JAK library to generate some KML and creating a style. For some reason the URL is being malformed and its turning '&' into '&amp'

```
document.createAndAddStyle().withId("styleTest").createAndSetIconStyle().withScale(1.399999976158142).withIcon(new Icon().withHref("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + ffffff ));
```

Result

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&amp;chld=%E2%80%A2|
```

What I need

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|
```

I didnt think it was java causing the problem but I could be wrong.

The value seems to be correct all the way up until its written using .marshall()

I dont think cdata will work

```
 <Style id="randomColorIcon">
            <IconStyle>
                <scale>1.399999976158142</scale>
                <heading>0.0</heading>
                <Icon>
                    <href>http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&amp;chld=%E2%80%A2|ff0000</href>
                    <refreshInterval>0.0</refreshInterval>
                    <viewRefreshTime>0.0</viewRefreshTime>
                    <viewBoundScale>0.0</viewBoundScale>
                </Icon>
            </IconStyle>
        </Style>
```

Cdata approach results in

```
 <href>&lt;![CDATA[http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&amp;chld=%E2%80%A2|ff0000]]&gt;</href>


String high = "<![CDATA[http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + ((PropertiesObj)this.prop.get(2)).maxColor;
```

Comment: Bare ampersands are invalid in XML, they need to be escaped to `&amp;`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328538/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-xml/1328557#1328557

Comment: [CDATA might work also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328538/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-xml/1328563#1328563)

Comment: updated with kml value. I dont think cdata will work for an href

Comment: I attempting to replace the & in the url to &amp; but it just replaced it with &amp;amp;. I also tried just amp; but that didnt work either. Nor did &amp;amp;...

Comment: Does anyone have ideas on why I cannot put an &amp; in the href on a XML

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work with JAK->KML

```
document.createAndAddStyle().withId("highPin").createAndSetIconStyle().withScale(1.399999976158142).withIcon(new Icon().withHref("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + ((PropertiesObj)this.prop.get(2)).maxColor));
```