# How to parse my string to XML with &nbsp elements?

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have string **s** and it looks:

```
<root><p>hello world</p>&nbsp;my name is!</root>
```

I have next code:

```
try
{
    m_Content = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(s));
}
catch (XmlException ex)
{
    ex.Data["myerror"] = s;

    throw;
}
```

As you see, I want to load string with all elements like `&nbsp;` and make it view. But I've got XmlException:

> Reference to undeclared substitution to "nbsp"

Any ideas how to do it right?

### Added

[ChrisShao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2706048/chris-shao) offered a good idea: put my string in `<![CDATA[` tag, but unfortunately it doesnt solve my problem. I have a big string with lots of tags and few big texts in which I can meet `&nbsp;` elements. If use `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` I lose all these elements and get " " fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Responding to your **Added** section. The blank (`" "`) fields you get is correct representation of `&nbsp;` when it is rendered. Correct encoding of `&nbsp;` for use in xml is `&#160;` [[Reference](http://changelog.ca/log/2006/06/12/making_nbsp_work_with_xml_rss_and_atom)].

If you really want to see `&nbsp;` instead of `" "` when the string loaded to `XDocument`, try to encode ampersand char (`&`) with `&amp;`. Replace `&nbsp;` with `&amp;nbsp;` [[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328538/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-xml)].

Answer (score 1):

use System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode or System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put your string into CDATA block,like this:

```
<root><![CDATA[<p>hello world</p>&nbsp;my name is!]]></root>
```

Comment: But how should I be if my string contains lots of tags and tonns of text where I can meet `&nbsp;` elements?

Comment: So what's the matter? it can't be parsed correct in CDATA?

Comment: Yep! I put `<![CDATA[` in the begin of string and `]]>` in the end. When I look on page I see `]]>` in the end of my shown elements. I think you'll agree with me that it shouldn't be there.