# how to keep &amp; when parsing an xml file using lxml and xpath

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xpath

I am trying to extract some information from an input xml file and print it into an output file by using lxml and xpath instructions.
I am getting a problem when reading an xml tag like the following

```
...
<editor> Barnes &amp; Nobel </editor>
...
```

In order to parse the xml file and print the editor content I use (there is always only one editor in the xml):

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8')
docTree = etree.parse( io.BytesIO(open(inputXML, "r").read()), parser )
print docTree.xpath('//editor')[0].text
```

My problem is that the `&amp;` gets converted at some point into `'&'`, which messes up my further processing.

How can I ensure that the `&amp;` symbol will not be "decoded"?

Comment: The `&amp;` is part of the *XML format*, not part of the data. It is like asking for the data to be kept in UTF-8 encoding. If you want it back, just escape the data yourself.

Comment: What 'further processing' gets messed up? If you are producing HTML output, use a proper HTML templating library that handles output escaping, for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters then I guess you are proposing that I do something like docTree = etree.parse( io.BytesIO(open(inputXML, "r").read().replace("&amp;", "\&amp;")), parser ) ?

Comment: I am not proposing anything like that. The *data in the XML document* is `Barnes & Nobel`, not `Barnes &amp; Nobel`, you are mistaking an XML escape sequence for data there. If you need to provide escaped data elsewhere *reapply the escaping*.

Answer (score 1):

I know this will sound presumptuous, but you want the data to be `"&"`.  That is the text content of the XML element.  If you have later processing that needs it as `"&amp;"`, then you need a step that will XML- (or HTML-) encode it back to `"&amp;"`,

You cannot ask an XML parser to parse your document and not turn `"&amp;"` into `"&"`.  It won't do it.

Comment: Thanks @Ned for your answer. All I want is that the output retains the exact same content as the input. I am using lxml to tell me what text exists inside a given tag, but I do not want it to do anything with the text. Can you propose a robust solution?

Comment: If you use lxml to output the XML again, it will turn the `&` back into `&amp;`.  You need to understand the tools you have.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer to my own question in the answer of [How do I escape ampersands in XML so they are rendered as entities in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328538/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-xml)
In my code I have added an intermediate step to ensure that all & characters will remain the same at the output. This is

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8')
xmlText = open(inputXML, "r").read().replace("&amp;", "&amp;amp;")
docTree = etree.parse( io.BytesIO(xmlText), parser )
print docTree.xpath('//editor')[0].text
```

In fact, just in case, I have applied the same recipe to other possible entities in XML as defined in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined%5Fentities%5Fin%5FXML

Comment: This step is unnecessary.  LXML will round-trip your data without corruption.

Comment: @NedBatchelder no, it does not :(. try `t = et.fromstring("<a>&apos;</a>"); print(et.tostring(t))`. It prints `b"<a>'</a>"`. It works with `&amp;` though

Comment: @CiprianTomoiaga I don't see how that is corruption. Those are equivalent representations of the same XML data.

Comment: hmm, ok. it just seemed strange I moved a node from a file to another, and in the second one it was "encoded" differently. And I tried everything to get it look the same

Comment: Why does it matter how it's encoded? Any XML parser will produce the same data from either representation.