# period symbol in xml causing issue

Tags: java, xml, json

i have a xml like below:

`<expectedJson>
{
"x":"give him $12&#46;25"
}
</expectedJson>`

What i am doing is: am comparing the json embeded with the actual json. But after parsing this xml, `&#46;` is getting converted to **.** i.e. period.

I want it to be interpreted as `&#46;` not as `.`. can anybody help on this?

Comment: You need to XML-escape your content.

Comment: do you generate your XML? if so, escape all your JSON data with CDATA (`<expectedJson><![CDATA[ {"x":"give him $12&#46;25"} ]]></expectedJson>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ampersand needs to be escaped to avoid it being treated as the start of an entity. [See this to escape the ampersand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328538/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-xml).

```
<expectedJson>
{
"x":"give him $12&#038;#46;25"
}
</expectedJson>
```

or

```
<expectedJson>
{
"x":"give him $12&amp;#46;25"
}
</expectedJson>
```

Answer (score 0):

XML has special characters like `&` that have a special meaning in XML. So you cannot use it directly as data. You need to escape it. For Eg. `&` should become `&amp;` after escaping it. For more details on handling special characters in XML, you can refer to my personal blog post -> [Escaping special characters of XML in Java](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2015/03/escaping-special-characters-of-xml-in.html)