# What request headers are required for a POST containing XML?

Tags: xml, excel, vba, post, httprequest

From Excel VBA, I am POSTing to an API that takes XML as one of the parameters.

It works fine unless there are ampersands(&) in the XML.
I have escaped them to `&amp;` but I still get an error back from the API telling me there are disallowed characters.

I am using the header as follow:

setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

The XML I am posting looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
    <row>
        <column id="747">ALROS TRAVEL &amp; HOLIDAY CO.</column>
        <column id="748">73318</column>
        <column id="749"/>
        <column id="750"/>
    </row>
</xml>
```

It appears that & is causing the issue based on my testing.

I have tested the XML through their testing tool and it works fine so I think the request headers are the problem.

I have asked the API developers to check what they receive from my POST and it appears to get cut off as soon as an & appears (even if it's escaped).

The only conclusions I could draw were that I'm using the wrong request headers, or that I should be posting the XML in a different way.

Their test tool is an HTML form which uses "multipart/form-data" but I can't seem to use that from VBA or I get "No authentication information is detected" message back.

Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the node in CDATA tags?  <![CDATA[ data goes here]]>

Comment: Try the solutions suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328538/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-xml)

Comment: Thanks guys, believe it or not the very last comment on the page @dePatinkin link gave me the answer. I had to use %26amp%3B

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218181/how-can-i-url-encode-a-string-in-excel-vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, believe it or not the very last comment on the page @dePatinkin link gave me the answer. I had to use %26amp%3B