# Generating xml file with "&" using java

Tags: java, xml, methods

I need to write `<name> Dolce & Gabanna </name>` in an xml file using java. However, what gets generated is `<name> Dolce &amp; Gabanna </name>`.

Is there any method I can use in java so `"&"` will be displayed in xml, instead of `"&amp;"`?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to generate the text in the XML file?

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328538/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-xml

Comment: Why would you want to generate invalid XML? The representation of `&` in XML *is* `&amp;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to write `<name> Dolce & Gabanna </name>` in an xml file using java.

No, you don't. Not unless you're *trying* to create an invalid file. Whatever code you're using is doing exactly the right thing - any XML parser *reading* the file will then unescape the `&amp;` to `&` where appropriate.

From the XML 1.0 specification, [section 2.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax):

> The ampersand character (`&`) and the left angle bracket (`<`) must not appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If they are needed elsewhere, they must be escaped using either numeric character references or the strings " `&amp;` " and " `&lt;` " respectively.

Comment: Would there be a way to display "&" if it is an invalid XML file? It doesn't matter to me if xml is valid or invalid because it will not be parsed, i only need the raw xml file.

Comment: @Isiah: Without the escaping, it *isn't* an XML file - not a valid one. You really need to decide whether you want valid XML, in which case you'll have `&amp;`, or plain text, in which case why bother with XML at all? Going for some sort of half-way house is a really bad idea.

Comment: If it doesn't matter to you whether the file is valid or invalid, then why do you refer to it as "XML"? What are you actually going to do with this non-XML file that you want to produce?