# Add '&' to WPF TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, string, xaml

I have a WPF form, for some reason ONLY **'&'** character within string cannot be compiled with.

```
<TextBox>=948&showtree=1</TextBox> <!--Error due to char &-->
```

I have tried:`<TextBox Text = @"=948&showtree=1"/>` yet, same result.

I have tried adding `"!@#$%^*()_+"` it also only happens with **'&'**. What is so special about **'&'** and how to overcome this problem within *xaml*?

I could add it in .cs file but I want to know why did this occurred.

Comment: XML is the same no matter which .NET version. Read about special characters in XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` is a special character in XML, which needs to be specified as `&amp;`, just like `&lt;` for `<` and `&gt;` for `>`.

So your line should read:

```
<TextBox>=948&amp;showtree=1</TextBox>
```

For more information on special characters in XML you can read this: http://xml.silmaril.ie/specials.html

Comment: I came across &amp but typed it without ; at end. Thanks for quick reply.

Answer (score 2):

The ampersand is a special character preceding other codes in XML - to use one you need to use the code for an ampersand which is `&amp;`

```
<TextBox>=948&amp;showtree=1</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode the ampersand.

Have you tried `&amp;` ?

See [How do I escape ampersands in XML so they are rendered as entities in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328538/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-xml)