# How to send Ampersand along with text in XML

Tags: asp.net, xml, rest

I was sending xml parameter to rest service like below

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://w3gana/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<Header>
<To xmlns="http://www.w3.svc</To>    
</Header>
<Body>
<tns:RetRES>
  <tns:EmpDef>        
        <studyChar>
          <I2:code code="QA Last" />
          <I2:value value="BDA & MAST" />
        </studyChar>         
    </I2:planStd>
  </tns:EmpDef>
 </tns:RetRES>
</Body>
</Envelope>
```

It was throwing error like "there is an unclosed literal string line 1", but it was accepting alphabets.

I have tried following strings instead of & but still i'm getting the same error.

&
&
&
&
&

Please help to resolve this

Comment: Have you tried escaping them like `\&` or use character data like `<![CDATA['&']]>`

Answer (score 2):

I think what you might be looking for is this: &amp

You can use that in place of & when coding in XML, certain charaters are illegal to use in XML such as <, and >.

Answer (score 0):

```
<To xmlns="http://www.w3.svc</To>
```

Aren't you missing the quotes after the url

```
<To xmlns="http://www.w3.svc"</To>
```

IF not then follow this link
[How do I escape ampersands in XML so they are rendered as entities in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328538/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-xml?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgotten to close your `To` tag

```
<To xmlns="http://www.w3.svc"></To>
```

If it doesn't fix it, you might want to try to escape it.

```
<I2:value value="BDA \& MAST" />
```

or

```
<I2:value value="BDA &amp; MAST" />
```

or

```
<I2:value value="BDA %26amp; MAST" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to escape an ampersand, have you tried. `&amp;`?

Also, you didn't close your To tag... it's missing a quote and the bracket.