# Want to write string "&quot" to xml file

Tags: python-3.x

Would like to write raw string "&quot" to value of an attribute.

using python minidom!

After writing "&quot" to XML file ,it looks like  "&ampquot" in the file.

pls help me on this....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape ampersands in XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328538/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-xml)

Comment: I just created an answer, but now I have a question.  Do you literally want `&quot`, or do you actually want `&quot;` (which is how a double quote character is encoded in an XML string).  If you really do want `&quot`, then it seems like `&amp;quot` is in fact how it *should* appear in the file, because `&amp;` represents the ampersand character.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regular double quote character in the string value of the attribute.  The code will take care of converting it to `&quot;` in the XML output.

Here's an example.  First, create the document:

```
In [52]: from xml.dom.minidom import getDOMImplementation

In [53]: impl = getDOMImplementation()

In [54]: doc = impl.createDocument(None, "tag", None)

In [55]: top_element = doc.documentElement
```

Set the "foo" attribute of the top element.  Note that there are double quotes in the string that will be the value of the "foo" attribute.

```
In [56]: top_element.setAttribute("foo", '"plate of shrimp"')
```

When the document is printed, those double quotes are converted to `&quot;`:

```
In [57]: print(top_element.toprettyxml())
<tag foo="&quot;plate of shrimp&quot;"/>
```