# How to do XML Transform in web.config where key value Demo 3pm&#8482

Tags: c#, xml, web-config

How to do xml- transform in web.config for key value = "Demo 3pm&#8482"

```
<add key="Key1" value="Demo 3pm&#8482;"></add>.
```

When I'm doing xml-transform it's giving

```
<add key="Key1" value="Demo 3pm™"></add> .
```

How to get `Demo 3pm&#8482`?

Comment: Question is unclear.... Please explain better and show some code..

Comment: Here is the actual key : <add key="Key1" value="Demo 3pm&#8482;" </add>. When I'm doing xml-transform it's giving <add key="Key1" value="Demo 3pm™"></add> . How to get Demo 3pm&#8482 ??

Comment: Please edit the question to add this code

Comment: So the problem is that you don't want the Xml Entity to be transformed into  its actual character?

Comment: @GiladGreen I don't think that dupe is correct

Comment: No Gilad, Rene,it's related XML-Transform. My question  is , XML transforming the web.config value basis of key. but XML Transform unable to convert it "Demo 3pm&#8482" as it is. It's giving result as "Demo 3pm™".

Comment: I think it might work if you do `Demo 3pm&amp;#8482;` as that will transform &amp; in & but will not consider the rest of the entity.

Comment: Thanks Rene !! It's now coming as Demo 3pm&amp;#8482 after xml- transform. Is there any way to make  as exact  3pm&#8482

Comment: Hmm, strange, maybe try `Demo 3pm&#038;#8482;` based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4940233/578411)

Comment: Rene , It gives me same result Demo 3pm&amp;#8482. How to rid out of amp;