# '&' inside element not validated by DTD how can i add in DTD to validate

Tags: xml, dtd

```
<doctitle>Sauerkraut & Sausages with a Little Goulash: Germans in Hollywood, 1927</doctitle>
```

In this doctitle i am getting '&' which is not validate by DTD how can i make it validate.

Comment: Escape it per XML standard: `&amp;`

Comment: There is nothing you can do in the DTD to fix this. You must escape all ampersands in the XML documents by changing `&` to `&amp;`. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax.

Comment: You mean we have to replace '&' to '&amp;' right?

Comment: Yes, you have to replace `&` with `&amp;` (with some exceptions; see mzjn's link).

Comment: Should be closed as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328538/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-xml-so-they-are-rendered-as-entities-in-html